# heroku client internal error - console timing out

Tags: heroku, timeout, heroku-toolbelt

heroku logs works, but heroku run console times out:

```
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.7335
```

!    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

```
Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
Backtrace:   /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `initialize'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `open'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:40:in `block in start'
             /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:31:in `start'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:132:in `rendezvous_session'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:119:in `run_attached'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:24:in `index'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
             /Users/username/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku run console
Plugins:     heroku-accounts
             heroku-fucking-console

Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.39.4 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Answer (score -3):

It looks like `heroku run:console` has been removed:

```
'heroku run:console' has been removed. Please use: `heroku run` instead.
```

Perhaps try doing:

```
heroku run bash
```